# I want to replace the MapFragment but it does not hide

Tags: android

I want to replace the MapFragment but it does not hide the two fragments come together.

What I want is to make it replace, work.
Since everything appears to me together, and neither the mapFragment nor the fragment two are understood

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenido,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(ActivityHome.class.getName());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

XML 

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.company.myapplication.Activity.ActivityHomeMap"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_activity_home_map"
    android:id="@+id/contenido">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapHome"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `Fragment`s declared in your layout cannot be removed/replaced dynamically. Load your `MapFragment` dynamically at startup instead. Also, if you're using support `Fragment`s, the `MapFragment` should be a `SupportMapFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that it's defined as a tag attribute
   `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`
**Hardcoded fragments** can't be replaced. Just *remove* the attribute and load it from java (dynamically) then do the replacing.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenido,fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(ActivityHome.class.getName());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: How could I upload the map programmatically?

Comment: Thank you, you can solve it, really. He had been stranded there.
Excuse my English, it is not my native language

Comment: I think you should ask another question.